# What am I missing. I want to check the response code of http Akka before processing JSON result

Tags: java, akka

I am new to Akka and java 8. So I am using pipe to call this method to call a REST service. 
It all works ok but would like to check response code before unmarshling json. or abort if response code is != 200. 
And is it correct with all these return null results?
........

My sample code:

```
CompletionStage<HttpResponse> fetch(LoginUserRequest input) {
        CompletionStage<HttpResponse> result = null;
*some json code*

        result = http.singleRequest(HttpRequest.POST(url).withEntity(HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON, jsonString)));


        result.thenCompose(response ->
        response.entity().toStrict(10000, materializer))
        .thenApply(entity -> {
            log.info("före");
            CompletionStage<UserResult> userResult = Jackson.unmarshaller(UserResult.class).unmarshal(entity, materializer);
            userResult.thenApply(unResult -> {
                requester.tell(new LoginUserResponse(unResult.getCredentials().getToken() != null, unResult.getCredentials().getToken()), self());
                return unResult;
            });
            return null;
        })
        .exceptionally(t -> {
            log.error("Exception occurred: " + t.getMessage());
            return null;
        });


        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the response code on your `response` object above. So you can check that and act accordingly. 
Within your first `.thenApply`, the return null should be wrong, since the result of `userResult.thenApply` wont be returned this way.